# Use the uncertainty principle to prove that $\int_{\mathbb R^n} (f(x))^2|\hat{f}(x)|^2 \,dx=0$ if and only if $f\equiv 0$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. Use the uncertainty principle to prove that $\int_{R^n} (f(x))^2|\hat{f}(x)|^2 \,dx=0$ if and only if $f\equiv 0$.

$\leftarrow$: If $f \equiv 0$ then $\int_{\mathbb R^n} (f(x))^2|\hat{f}(x)|^2 \,dx=\int_{\mathbb R^n} (0)^2|\hat{f}(x)|^2 \,dx=\int_{\mathbb R^n} 0 \,dx=0$

**Done**

$\rightarrow$: If $\int_{\mathbb R^n} (f(x))^2|\hat{f}(x)|^2 \,dx=0$, then $\ldots$
The uncertainty principle states
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} |x|^2|f(x)|^2 \,dx\int_{\mathbb R^n} |y|^2|\hat{f}(y)|^2 \,dx \geq (2 \pi)^{-2n}||f||_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}^4$$

How am I suppose to use this fact to prove this direction?

Comment: If $f\not\equiv 0$ then $\lVert f\rVert>0$

Comment: just a $\LaTeX$ tip: $\in$ is obtained using "in" command, looks much better than using $\epsilon$ ("epsilon")

Comment: @mm-aops Thank you for the tip

Comment: @AdamHughes How do I use the fact that the norms of f is positive

Comment: It implies that the integral is also necessarily positive, hence that the function cannot be identically zero.